# Room Database Query Starting with a letter

Tags: android

I want to display songs from table starting with a specified letter in Room Database

Here is my Query

@Dao
public interface SongDao 
{

```
@Insert
public void addSong(SongEntity songEntity);

@Query( "SELECT * FROM malayalam where title LIKE :letter '%' ")
List<SongEntity>getSongs(String letter);
```

here letter will replaced by A,B,C, ...etc
please help.

Answer (score 3):

Use this code

```
@Query( "SELECT * FROM malayalam where title LIKE :letter||'%' ")
List<SongEntity>getSongs(String letter);
```

you have to add '||' before '%'.
It will work fine